# Identifying specific resources that are overallocated in MS Project using TimeScale

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have multiple resources (learners, Facilitators and Rooms) allocated to Tasks (training sessions) and I want to identify which are double-booked and then adding them into a text column.

I am using the TimeScale method and I am currently trying to calculate a double-booking by assuming that any resource that has more time than the length of the session allocated to them over a given start and end date for that session must be double-booked.

However I cannot work out how to determine the total amount of time they have been assigned.  The pjTimeScale attribute does not seem to be returning what i need.  Using pjTimescaleHours is the closest to the actual value that should be returned.

What am I missing?  or is there a better approach?

```
Sub Overallocations()
'T.Text19 is the Overallocation column
'Identify the overallocations and the source ID
Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource
Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues

Dim asn As Assignment

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
T.Text19 = ""
Next T

'Start the allocation of Rooms process
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

i = 0

Application.StatusBar = "Checking Session No." & T.ID
'Checks to see if the task is a valid Module session and if it has been 
confirmed. Skips if not a session or if its a confirmed session
If Left(T.Name, 1) <> "M" Then
    GoTo SkipT
End If

For Each R In T.Resources

    Set tsvs = R.TimeScaleData(T.Start, T.Finish, pjResourceTimescaledWork, 
pjTimescaleHours)
    Duration = (T.Finish - T.Start) * 60 * 24


    If tsvs(1).Value > Duration + 1 Then  'THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING
        If T.Text19 = "" Then
            T.Text19 = R.Name
        Else
            T.Text19 = T.Text19 & ", " & R.Name
        End If
    End If
Next R

SkipT:
Next T 'Next Task

MsgBox "The identification of overallocation has been completed.", 
vbInformation, "Resource Overallocation Complete"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple resources (learners, Facilitators and Rooms) allocated to Tasks (training sessions) and I want to identify which are double-booked...

In other words, need to identify learners, facilitators, and rooms that are assigned to **overlapping training sessions**.

While this can be done using the `TimeScaleData` method, a far easier approach is to look for overlapping sessions. There are four scenarios where training sessions overlap:

- Class B starts before Class A and finishes while Class A is still running.
- Class B starts while Class A is running and finishes after Class A.
- Class B starts and finishes while Class A is running.
- Class B starts before Class A and finishes after Class A.

**All four scenarios can be identified with a common expression:** `Class B starts before Class A ends and Class B ends after Class A starts`; see diagram below.

[image: graphical explanation of how two time frames can overlap (or not)]

Here is your code adapted for this method:

```
Sub IdentifyOverlappingAssignments()

Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

    Application.StatusBar = "Checking Session No." & T.ID

    T.Text19 = vbNullString

    'Checks to see if the task is a valid Module session and if it has been confirmed.
    If Left(T.Name, 1) = "M" Then

        For Each R In T.Resources

            ' check to see if this resource is assigned to another task
            ' at all during the duration of this task
            Dim asn As Assignment
            For Each asn In R.Assignments
                If asn.Task.UniqueID <> T.UniqueID Then
                    ' do the tasks overlap?
                    If asn.Task.Finish > T.Start And asn.Task.Start < T.Finish Then
                        If T.Text19 = "" Then
                            T.Text19 = R.Name & " (" & asn.Task.ID & ")"
                        Else
                            T.Text19 = T.Text19 & ", " & R.Name & " (" & asn.Task.ID & ")"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next asn

        Next R
    End If
Next T

MsgBox "The identification of overallocation has been completed." _
    , vbInformation, "Resource Overallocation Complete"

End Sub
```

Note: using TimeScaleData is problematic in this case for various reasons including: 1) resources *could* be assigned at 50% usage and would not be identified as double-booked because the would not be overallocated, 2) if classes started on the half hour (e.g. 10:30 AM - 12:00 PM), you would need to get the timescale values down to the minute because using pjTimescaleHours will return the full hour (e.g. the timescale values will start at 10:00 AM), and that's an easy bug to introduce to your code.

Comment: BTW The logic used to find overlapping resource bookings also works to identify tasks that fall within a given range. For example use it to "list all tasks being worked on in the next 90 days".

Answer (score 0):

Two things, one pointer about the code and one question.

1. If you are for...nexting through the tasks collection remember to
   put an If..Then just inside it like this one to catch blank rows.
   PMs LOVE blank rows and they will error out your code. I also do it
   for resources because sometimes they will put blank rows there too.
2. Can I ask why you are doing this instead of using the built in
   'Overallocated' functionality in Project? If a resource is assigned
   more than 1 hour of work in any given hour then that resource will
   automatically get flagged as such as will any task to which they are
   assigned. This is cool code but SHOULD be unnecessary unless Im
   missing something.

Code:

```
Sub Foo()
Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource
    For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not (T Is Nothing) Then
            'Task stuff
            For Each R In T.Resources
                If Not (R Is Nothing) Then
                    Resource Stuff
                End If
            Next R
        End If
    Next T
End Sub
```